# Swift: Use wildcard as generic type parameter

Tags: generics, swift, wildcard

I'd like to store instances of a class derived from a generic type in a Dictionary; that is, the Dictionary should store an instance of *any* class derived from this generic.

Something like this:

```
class ParentClass {}
class ChildClass: ParentClass {}

class GenericClass<T: ParentClass> {
    var foo:T?
}

typealias DerivedClass = GenericClass<ChildClass>

class TestGenerics {

    var dict: Dictionary<String, GenericClass<**what goes here??**>> = [:]

    func test() {
        var derivedClassInstance = DerivedClass()
        dict.updateValue(derivedClassInstance, forKey: "name")
    }
}
```

This is fairly straightforward in Java:

```
public class TestGenericsOuter {

    class ParentClass {}
    class ChildClass extends ParentClass {}

    class GenericClass<T extends ParentClass> {
        T foo;
    }

    class DerivedClass extends GenericClass<ChildClass> {}

    class TestGenerics {

        Dictionary<String, GenericClass<? extends ParentClass>> dict;

        void test() {
            DerivedClass derivedClassInstance = new DerivedClass();
            dict.put("name", derivedClassInstance);

        }
    }

}
```

Is something like this possible in Swift?  The only way I've gotten this to work is to just create a Dictionary with "Any" as the value type.  But, then I lose some type safety, so I'd like to avoid this solution if possible.

Comment: Right -- that's what I meant to say: I can use a Dictionary with Any as the value type. (I put the angle brackets and the parser ate them, I guess).  I'd like to use a more specific type restriction so I don't need to cast everything I get out of the Dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can mimic Java's wildcard, but you might not need to either. You can just use `ChildClass` wherever the code is expecting a `ParentClass`. So using your example:

```
class TestGenerics {
    var dict: Dictionary<String, GenericClass<ParentClass>> = [:]

    func test() {
        var derivedClassInstance = GenericClass<ParentClass>()
        dict.updateValue(derivedClassInstance, forKey: "name")
    }
}
```

Now just use `ChildClass` to fill in `foo`

```
let test = TestGenerics()
test.test()
test.dict["name"]?.foo = ChildClass()
```

That code compiles without errors. However, Swift doesn't support covariance on custom generics classes so you can't change the dictionary with a covariant type, so the following doesn't compile:

```
test.dict = Dictionary<String, GenericClass<ChildClass>>()
//Error: 'ChildClass' is not identical to 'ParentClass'
```

This is not very intuitive, since covariance is indeed supported on native Array and Dictionaries, so this is allowed:

```
let array: Array<ParentClass> = Array<ChildClass>()
let dic: Dictionary<String, ParentClass> = Dictionary<String, ChildClass>()
```

But not this:

```
let generic: GenericClass<ParentClass> = GenericClass<ChildClass>()
//Error: 'ChildClass' is not identical to 'ParentClass'
```

Basically Swift treats `Array<ChildClass>` as a subtype of `Array<ParentClass>` but it isn't possible at the moment to tell the compiler that `GenericClass<ChildClass>` is (or should be) a subtype of `GenericClass<ParentClass>`. Hopefully, as the language evolves, a way to declare custom classes as covariant will be added.

Comment: If Swift treats `Array<ChildClass>` as a subtype of `Array<ParentClass>` then what happens when `var vehicles: Array<Vehicle> = Array<Bike>()` and then `vehicles.append(myCar)`?

Comment: That's a good question @Andreas. Just tried on a Playground and apparently that's valid code. If you do `vehices.dynamicType`, it returns that vehicles is an `Array<Vehicle>` even though it was constructed using `Array<Bike>()`. That was unexpected.

Comment: @asayagogalvan Array types in Swift are value types. Thus the type is part of the variable and not the value (in contrast to Java's `List<T>`, which is a reference type). Swift's `Array.append()` creates a new value and stores it in the original variable. If the variable has a permissive enough type, the new value can be stored there. This does not depend on where the old value came from and what type the original variable had because the old and new values are not related to each other.

Answer (score -1):

You need to parameterize the type containing whatever reference is to be made generic, and use a type constraint there. Also, the typealias relates to the constraints on the parameterized type, so it goes inside that type.

```
class ParentClass {}
class ChildClass: ParentClass {}

class GenericClass<T: ParentClass> {
    var foo:T?
}


class TestGenerics<T: ParentClass> {
    typealias DerivedClass = GenericClass<T>

    var dict: Dictionary<String, GenericClass<T>> = [:]

    func test() {
        var derivedClassInstance = DerivedClass()
        dict.updateValue(derivedClassInstance, forKey: "name")
    }
}

let blah = TestGenerics<ChildClass>()
let baz = GenericClass<ChildClass>()
baz.foo = ChildClass()
blah.dict = ["a":baz]
```

Comment: That seems like it's just "passing the buck" to TestGenerics.  What if TestGenerics shouldn't be parameterized?

Comment: But your way a particular dictionary can only hold one type of `GenericClass`, i.e. for only a particular `T`. In Java something like `Dictionary<String, GenericClass<? extends ParentClass>>` is a dictionary that can hold all different `GenericClass`es at the same time.